# MySQL ForeignKey: set null on update timestamp

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've got a table `ch_img` that stores images with the cells `id, filename, width, height, removed_at`.
The table gets updates on the width and height sometimes and a row will never be deleted. The deletion is handled by updating the `removed_at` cell from NULL to a timestamp.
I have another table `ch_services` with a foreign key on a cell `image` to the cell `id` of the `ch_img` table.
I now want to set to `image` cell of `ch_services` to NULL when I update the `removed_at` cell of `ch_img`.
Basically a kind of `ON DELETE SET NULL` but there is no DELETE, there is an update. But I don't want to set to Null when I update the `width/height` cell of `ch_img`. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to handle tasks like this; the way you ask the question suggests that using a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) would fit your needs. That would allow you to write logic that would look at changes to `ch_img` and conditionally update the other table. The documentation for triggers is pretty good, with lots of examples.

Your code would look something like:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON ch_img
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.removed_at > 0 THEN
      UPDATE ch_services SET img_id = NULL WHERE img_id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

However, there is a reason not to use triggers that you should consider. Consider that you are writing business logic in a secret hiding place, away from all your other code. It's easy to lose track of triggers or forget they even exist.

I would argue that unless performance is a big concern, your code will be easier to maintain if you keep all your logic in one place. In that case, you can just write the extra queries in your code.

There are other people, I'm sure, who would disagree with me strongly.

Triggers will definitely get the job done, but the right answer depends on whether processor-milliseconds are worth more than engineer-hours.

Comment: Very good answer - thank you! I hear from triggers the first time but I like them. But I absolutely agree with you that can lose track of triggers very easily. I thought there is a more simple option on a foreign key to handle this. If not, I better keep my logic in my code as you suppose.